# using dynamic list data in d3.js

Tags: c#, asp.net, d3.js

I have retrieved data from c# web method in the form of lists, i need to populate the data in the form of a line chart using the D3 JavaScript library. How can i do that?

How do I use the list data in D3 and have the date time format in one list and the value in another list?

```
 $.ajax({
 url: "ServiceMessage.asmx/GetPostings",
        type: "POST",
        contentType:"application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            var myData = data.d;
            var data1;
            var data2;
            alert(myData.length + " hellos");
            for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
               // $("#divMsg").append(myData[i].date + " " + myData[i].values);
                 data1[i] = myData[i].date; "</br>"
                  data2[i] = myData[i].values; "</br>"
                 $("#divMsg").append(data1[i]+""+data2[i])
            }
```

How can I use data1 data2 to populate a line graph?

Comment: Have a look at [the example provide by Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3883245/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look here http://www.d3noob.org/2012/12/starting-with-basic-d3-line-graph.html

Your case is even simpler because you already have your data in a list. Do not split it in two arrays, it is better to have one list [{date:... , value:...},{date:..., value:...}... ]

you have to init d3 (as you can see there is a "time" range for the x axis, if you use it you can parse the dates with the d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse function):

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

/* ---------------------- This is your line --------------------- */
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });
/* -------------------------------------------------------------- */

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

and then append the line (where data is the list of {date:..., value:...}:

```
svg.append("path")      // Add the valueline path.
    .attr("d", valueline(data));

svg.append("g")         // Add the X Axis
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")         // Add the Y Axis
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

PS: I use "value" here but in your question you use "values".

Comment: i have datetime of c# format  how do i parse that?(26-08-2014 07:14:43) in this format

Comment: oh yes, you are right you have to parse. you have to apply d3.time.format(...).parse to the date attribute to each object in your data list : `data.forEach(function(d) { d.time = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S").parse(d.date) });`  see [link](http://www.d3noob.org/2012/12/formatting-date-time-on-d3js-graph.html)